# Failed to launch browser with “https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth”, Access denied

Tags: c#, google-authentication, google-oauth

I am downloading files from Google Drive, so I am using Google oauth2 
authentication in C#.

It was working so good, but suddenly, exception like below is occurred.

"Failed to launch browser with “https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth”, Access denied"

Please help me.